# Extend form background past container

Tags: css

I'm trying to find a way to extend the grey background of the form on this page past the top and bottom of the background image below, so it looks like it sitting above it.

https://www-databeat-net.sandbox.hs-sites.com/-temporary-slug-63cfc60c-4815-4281-a89c-33528a74a424?h...

I have tried changing the overflow visibility of the container to visible, but then the background image doesn't fill the height of the container.

I'm looking for the grey background to extend slightly beyond the top and bottom of the background image behind.

Any ideas on how to do this are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: remove border-top from .glfoot-footerbackground

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the border-top from your .glfoot-footerbackground class. like this:

```
.glfoot-footerbackground {
    background: #282828;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 20rem;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 15px #ababab;
}
```